# Class variable in multiprocessing - python

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing, dill

Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing
import dill

class Some_class():

    class_var = 'Foo'

    def __init__(self, param):
        self.name = param

    def print_name(self):

        print("we are in object "+self.name)
        print(Some_class.class_var)

def run_dill_encoded(what):
    fun, args = dill.loads(what)
    return fun(*args)


def apply_async(pool, fun, args):
    return pool.apply_async(run_dill_encoded, (dill.dumps((fun, args)),))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    list_names = [Some_class('object_1'), Some_class('object_2')]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    results = [apply_async(pool, Some_class.print_name, args=(x,)) for x in list_names]
    output = [p.get() for p in results]
    print(output)
```

It returns error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\...\temp_obj_output_standard.py", line 18, in run_dill_encoded
    return fun(*args)
  File "C:/...temp_obj_output_standard.py", line 14, in print_name
    print(Some_class.class_var)
NameError: name 'Some_class' is not defined
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/...temp_obj_output_standard.py", line 31, in <module>
    output = [p.get() for p in results]
  File "C:/...temp_obj_output_standard.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
    output = [p.get() for p in results]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 599, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: name 'Some_class' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code works fine without line `print(Some_class.class_var)`. What is wrong with accessing class variables, both objects should have it and I don't think processes should conflict about it. Am I missing something?
Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot it? Do not worry about `run_dill_encoded` and 
`apply_async`, I am using this solution until I compile `multiprocess` on Python 3.x.

P.S. This is already enough, but stackoverflow wants me to put more details, not really sure what to put.

Comment: Oi! I ran your code with python2.7 and python3.4 and it returned with zero: we are in object object_1
Foo
we are in object object_2
Foo
[None, None]

Comment: @krysopath. I am running it on python 3.4 and still getting an error

Comment: The only obvious differerence between us, that I use debian, while you are using a Microsoft OS of some version, could be a hint. Perhaps you installed some buggy libs or your python interpreter is broken. Your code runs just fine here. You could try to run it it in Cygwin first and in a virtual machine with some other non Microsoft OS after, to check if it is working there.

Comment: @krysopath, I have VirtualBox, I will try it there. Do you have Anaconda or clean Python installation.

Comment: I am on vanilla python from debians stable repos. python 2.7.9 and 3.4.2

Comment: @krysopath, Thank you, it worked on Ubuntu! I wonder why and how to troubleshoot?

Comment: I believe your trouble is being caused by the fact that multiproccessing in windows has no fork like unices do. Following this accepted answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596617/python-multiprocess-diff-between-windows-and-linux

Comment: @krysopath. You are the man! How did you find it? Another solution would be to use threads `from multiprocessing import dummy`

Comment: Hi I'm the `dill` and `multiprocess` author.  If you are on non-Windows and want to check the Windows "fork" behavior, you can use `dill.check` (on Windows it does the same as `dill.copy`, of course).  BTW. `dill.copy` is `dill.loads(dill.dumps(object))`.  I'd suggest using `multiprocess`, however, as it's just more direct.

Comment: Were you able to move past this with `multiprocess`?  To use `multiprocess` you will need a C++ compiler, and if you are on Windows, Microsoft provides a free compiler suitable (via download) for use with Python.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I need to dig it. I already forgot what I did. Is compiler for Python 2.x only? or does it for Python 3.x?

Comment: The windows compiler can be downloaded for python 2.x or python 3.x.  Note that `multiprocess` doesn't actually need a C++ compiler for more recent versions (3.3 and above, I think) of python 3.x.