# Python process starting after two lines of code

Tags: python, process

I'm making a class that subclasses `multiprocessing.Process`.
When doing some testing,
I noticed that the process was not starting when `start()` was called.
After some testing, it appears that the processes do not start until 2 lines of code are executed in the `__main__` module.

As an example

```
import multiprocessing

class Test(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('created')

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).run(*args, **kwargs)
        print('running')

sample = Test()
>>> created
sample.start()
pass # Did not start yet
pass # Will start after this
>>> running
```

I've tested this on different platforms, and it works as expected there.
I'm running Windows 10, Python 3.5.2.
Output of `sys.version` is `'3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'`

Comment: Are you always running from a python interactive session?  Do you get the same when executing the code as a script from the command-line?

Comment: It always appears to be the same, whether its from an interactive session, a script, or importing a module.

Answer (score 0):

It is known that multiprocessing behaves differently under windows and linux.  By other platforms do you mean linux?  Multiprocessing forks (with `fork()`) a new process in linux and the child process gets a copy of all the variables and information it needs, where Windows spawns a new copy of the python interpreter for each process.  There is a good answer explaining it here:
[Python Multiprocess diff between Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596617/python-multiprocess-diff-between-windows-and-linux)

So to remedy, make sure that all global variables are explicitly passed to the child processes using shared memory.  Check out the multiprocessing docs:
https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes for a bit more information.